# Using sparse_softmax_cross_entropy() with unequal number of examples in each class

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, text-classification

I am working on convolutional neural network based text classifier. I am using the `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy()` on my `logits` tensor to get the loss but it is producing the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Received a label value
of -9223372036854775808 which is outside the valid range of [0, 9).
```

Based on what I could gather this is due to unequal number of examples across my classes(I tried running the classifier with equal number of examples for each class, but this gives a final accuracy of just 0.11). The difference of examples is not that profound given that I have 16542 examples spread across 9 classes and with 6 classes consisting of 2001, and three with 1452, 1300 and 1787 examples. How can I get the classifier to work without reducing the number of examples I have for training.

Comment: I don't think this is due to an unbalanced number of labels (why would it be?) which is what we have 99% of the time. The error literally says "you're feeding a bad number to the label tensor", did you check your inputs?

Comment: No such value is present in my input data-frame. Moreover, I concluded that the error occurred due to unequal number of examples because using `dropna()` on the data-frame before feeding it to the network resolves the issue.

Comment: So you have missing values in your data. Of course you shouldn't feed them into tensorflow. This still has nothing to do with unbalanced classes.